# How to emulate effect of mutual inductance?

Tags: circuit-analysis, mutual-inductance

### Background

I don't have any background in electrical engineering. My knowledge is very superficial. I am simulating a circuit which has mutual inductance between two components. However, the software package I want to use ([JosephsonCircuits](https://github.com/kpobrien/JosephsonCircuits.jl)) to simulate does not allow any method to set the mutual inductance. For example, another simulator that I have used for the same task ([WRSpice](http://wrcad.com/wrspice.html)) allows you to specify mutual inductance between two components.

---

### Question

So, my question is: Is there any way to emulate the effect of mutual inductance by only using capacitors, resistors and inductors? Is there a way to construct an equivalent circuit?

---

### Details

The following is the circuit I want to simulate:

[image]

---

### My attempt

Looking at some online resources, it seems that I can emulate the behaviour of the above circuit using the following circuit:

[image]

---

Is that correct? If not, what would be an equivalent circuit that gives the same effects as the one with mutual inductance but only uses the circuit components and no mutual inductance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt needs a fix. Try this:

[image]

Verify it by inserting something to both sides and writing the KVL equations.

M = the mutual inductance. It's the squareroot of the product of L1 and L2 only if there's 100% magnetic coupling.

This can be used if the calculation software doesn't get mad after seeing negative L1-M or L2-M.

**ADD:** I became curious - does this math triviality work in practice? Does a circuit analyzer stay numerically stable with negative inductance? I tried in Micro-Cap a transformer L1=1H, M=2H, L2=4H. That's a 1:2 voltage boosting transformer.

It worked both in AC and Transient analysis. The only hitch is that there must be some resistance in input to prevent direct inductor-only loop connected to a voltage source. But that's for all circuits in Micro-Cap, not only for this one.

Negative inductor seemingly doesn't cause unstability when it's there as a single component among others which together form a stable circuit. The situation might be different if one tries to simulate the negative inductor with a self contained feedback stabilized circuit. I cannot prove it, but intuitively it looks like it's an endless energy source which cannot settle to any operating point if someone connects a slightest voltage to it.

Comment: Yes, in my case, I have 100% coupling. So I only need to change $L_1 + \sqrt{L_1 L_2}$ to $L_1 - \sqrt{L_1 L_2}$ instead?

Comment: your equations do not get rendered. But try this https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8qgW.jpg Factor k=1 for 100% coupling. Note also the places of the coupling polarity dots at the transformer coil ends in my original image.

Answer (score 1):

> the software package I want to use (JosephsonCircuits) to simulate does not allow any method to set the mutual inductance

Are you sure? Mutual inductance is a feature listed in the first sentence of the README file! Emphasis mine:

> JosephsonCircuits.jl is a high-performance frequency domain simulator for nonlinear circuits containing Josephson junctions, capacitors, inductors, **mutual inductors**, and resistors.

If the documentation isn't clear on how to achieve that, you can probably file a GitHub issue with the project to ask for a clarification/improvement in the documentation. Have you had a close look at the example circuits?

Comment: The software package does not seem to have any documentation, and none of the examples they have provided seem to use mutual inductance. I briefly went over the source code and was not able to understand it. Thank you for your suggestion about raising a GitHub issue. Regardless of the ability of this particular software to simulate mutual inductors, I would still like to get the answer to my question: *Is there a way to construct an equivalent circuit?*

Comment: @FDGod Sure, does the thing support dependent sources? Then at least you'll know what search terms to use. With the basic assortment of VCVS, VCCS, CCVS, CCCS, you have everything needed to simulate mutual inductors. In fact, in many a Spice they'd be simulated that way.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have enough understanding of the terminology to answer your question. I will read about things and will get back to you. (Although it seems that other answer has provided me what I was looking for)

Answer (score 1):

Author of [JosephsonCircuits.jl](https://github.com/kpobrien/JosephsonCircuits.jl) here. You can include mutual inductance with the mutual coupling coefficient `K`. Here is an example where we see a mutual inductance results in the same scattering parameters as the T-circuit provided by @arnold8a:

```
# inductively coupled LC resonator example
using DSP
using Plots
using JosephsonCircuits

@variables R1 L1 K1 L2 C1

# netlist with a mutual inductor
circuit1 = [
    ("P1","1","0",1),
    ("R1","1","0",R1),
    ("L1","1","0",L1),
    ("K1","L1","L2",K1),
    ("L2","2","0",L2),
    ("C1","2","0",C1)]

# netlist with T circuit equivalent to mutual inductor
circuit2 = [
    ("P1","1","0",1),
    ("R1","1","0",R1),
    ("La","1","2",L1-K1*sqrt(L1*L2)),
    ("Lb","2","0",K1*sqrt(L1*L2)),
    ("Lc","2","3",L2-K1*sqrt(L1*L2)),
    ("C1","3","0",C1)]

circuitdefs = Dict(
    L1 =>1000e-12,
    L2 =>2000e-12,
    C1 => 900e-15,
    R1 => 50.0,
    K1 => 0.1,
)
w=2*pi*(3.5:0.01:4.0)*1e9
sol1 = hblinsolve(w,circuit1,circuitdefs);
sol2 = hblinsolve(w,circuit2,circuitdefs);

plot(sol1.w/(2*pi*1e9),
    unwrap(angle.(sol1.S(
            outputmode=(0,),
            outputport=1,
            inputmode=(0,),
            inputport=1,
            freqindex=:),
    )),
    ylim=(-2pi,1.1*pi),
    label="mutual inductor",
    xlabel="Frequency (GHz)",
    ylabel="Phase (radians)",
    linewidth=2,
)

plot!(sol2.w/(2*pi*1e9),
    unwrap(angle.(sol2.S(
            outputmode=(0,),
            outputport=1,
            inputmode=(0,),
            inputport=1,
            freqindex=:),
    )),
    label="T-circuit equivalent",
    linestyle=:dash,
    linecolor=:black,
    linewidth=2,
)
```

[image]

If you have questions about the code or find bugs, you are welcome to open an issue or start a discussion at the Github repo.

Answer (score 0):

### ___________________________________________________________________________"Question:
*Is there any way to emulate the effect of mutual inductance by only using capacitors, resistors and inductors? Is there a way to construct an equivalent circuit?*"

You could use a particular circuit that simulates inductance. The demonstration that it behaves like an inductance is in the following photo followed by a possible circuit:

[image]
[image]

Comment: L1-M or L2-M can be negative. The simulated inductance circuit is a self-contained feedback-stabilized unit. Does it stay stable also in negative inductance case? I guess it's useless to try to build one, but does it stay stable in a circuit simulator when one tries to do time domain and frequency domain analyses?

Comment: @arnold8a I drew up the circuit thinking about the inductance simulator. I'm evaluating the case of negative values.

Answer (score 0):

Choose a coupling coefficient k such that the two differences between the inductances and the mutual inductance are positive. However, the result of the simulation is not the desired one given that the output buffer, having very high input impedance, does not allow the passage of current and therefore does not work, but there should be passage of current.
[image]